# Null check operator used on a null value || Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, expandablelistview, flutter-futurebuilder, flutter-listview

The null check operator used on a null value error comes up sometimes on the UI otherwise a circular progress indicator shows up.
the error shows up in the 266 line.

```
class Orders extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_OrdersState createState() => _OrdersState();
}

 class _OrdersState extends State<Orders> {
  OrdersModel? order;
  OrdersModel? order2;

void modelData() async {
order2 = await ordersModel();
setState(() {
  order = order2;
});
}

  @override
  void initState() {
   modelData();
   _futureOrdersModel = ordersModel();
   // ordersModel();
   super.initState();
  } 

Widget categories() {
  return buildFutureBuilder();
 }

  @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: primaryColor,
  body: Container(
    child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
         );
}

 late Future<OrdersModel>? _futureOrdersModel;
  FutureBuilder<OrdersModel> buildFutureBuilder() {
   return FutureBuilder<OrdersModel>(
     future: _futureOrdersModel,
     builder: (context, snapshot) {
       if (snapshot.hasData) {
        bool? checkedValue =
             
  order?.data.attributes.totalBills[0].manualBillCompletion 
     ??   true;
       return ListView.builder(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        itemCount: snapshot.data?.data.attributes.totalBills.length ?? 0,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.push(context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Review()));
            },
           
                ],
              ),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius:
                      BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(15))),
            ),
          ); //categoryCard1();
        },
      );
    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return Text('${snapshot.error}');
    }
 
    return Column(
      children: [
        Center(child: const CircularProgressIndicator()),
      ],
    );
  },
 );
 }
 }
```

**check my console error to get it more clear of my errors**

[image: This is my error in console]

in console, it shows error due to **bottomNavigation** [here is the code for that also](https://pastebin.pl/view/4d1a5720)

Comment: the error is in `CustomOrder` share `CustomOrder` code.

Comment: Hello @Hadi, here is the  [CustomerOrder.dart](https://pastebin.pl/view/c17a4572)

Answer (score 1):

this null check error because I am using bang operator (!) to suppress the error. But on run time when my app runs this error shows up.

example:- How to use ? and ?? operator properly

```
String? name; //Here name is a nullable variable

void main()
{
var len = name?.length?? 0;
}
```

if the name is null then the value will be appointed 0.

so in the itemCount of the listview.builder I used ?? operator like this.

```
itemCount: customer?.data.length?? 0,
```